# jquery getJSON error

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I'm using this code below

```
$.getJSON('/list_pat', function(data){
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    console.log("val  "+ val);
  });
});
```

where the /list_pat is returning

```
    "{'patients':[{'ailment': [{'ailment': 'alksjdnfkajcbkasjcbksd', 'updatedby': ''
 'datecreated': '2013-05-20 18:53:13', 'ailtag': '11', 'prescription': 'kjnckasjcnksjdnc',
 'dateupdated': '', 'images': [{'desc': 'ksjcnksajcnd', 'datecreated': '', 'addedby': '2013-
05-20 18:53:22', 'imgtag': '30'}], 'createdby': '', 'procedure': 'kjnaksjncksdjnc'}]]}
```

after trying the above code i'm getting an error on the console in the chrome browser.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '143' in         "{'patients':[{'ailment': [{'ailment': 'alksjdnfkajcbkasjcbksd', 'updatedby': ''
     'datecreated': '2013-05-20 18:53:13', 'ailtag': '11', 'prescription': 'kjnckasjcnksjdnc',
     'dateupdated': '', 'images': [{'desc': 'ksjcnksajcnd', 'datecreated': '', 'addedby': '2013-
    05-20 18:53:22', 'imgtag': '30'}], 'createdby': '', 'procedure': 'kjnaksjncksdjnc'}]]}
```

the 143 is the total length of the string. Am i missing something. I just want to parse the JSON .

Comment: If this is really the returned value, it's a JSON encoded string containing (somewhat similar to) JSON data. So you would need to decode it again.

Comment: JSON file doesn't start with double quotes. I guess that is the problem.

Comment: I suspect the server has encoded its object twice. But the first time doesn't look like valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON you are trying to work with is invalid.

Valid JSON strings are encapsulated by double-quotes (") where your JSON strings are encapsulated by single quotes (').

Comment: you are right, but also parse the object..

Comment: @DoryZidon `$.getJSON` returns a JSON object, not a string.

Comment: you are right my bad..

Comment: The problem is that while `$.getJSON` indeed tries to supply an Object  (= result of `JSON.parse`) into `$.each`, obviously in this case `$.each` walks over a string (failing still) - because the response is actually considered a JSONed string.

Comment: @rakesh, really, this was your selected answer?  It's wrong.  Doesn't matter whether you use double or single quotes. The problem, as razzak correctly pointed out, is that your JSON was missing a comma and a closing curly bracket.  Regardless of which you select, his was the correct answer, not this one!

Comment: @DerekHenderson While the missing bracket and comma are also issues (and I agree that they are just as much an issue as using incorrect quotes), my answer is not wrong as you say. You need to read up on the [JSON spec](http://json.org/) because while Javascript allows single or double quotes without issue, valid JSON, which is what jQuery's getJSON() function works with, specifically requires double quotes.

Comment: @winterblood, I'm very well aware of the JSON spec.  But the issue of single-quotes vs double-quotes was not the reason why the OP's code was failing.  The code fails equally with double quotes, and it is in that sense that this answer is wrong.  The correct answer is that `data` needs to be a correctly formed object. The code runs equally well with single quotes -- go ahead and try it -- but generates an error with the missing comma and bracket.

Answer (score 1):

you have syntax error in json:

```
data = {'patients':[
            {'ailment': [
                {'ailment': 'alksjdnfkajcbkasjcbksd', 
                 'updatedby': '',  //missing ","
                 'datecreated': '2013-05-20 18:53:13', 
                 'ailtag': '11', 
                 'prescription': 'kjnckasjcnksjdnc', 
                 'dateupdated': '',
                 'images': [
                    {'desc': 'ksjcnksajcnd', 
                     'datecreated': '', 
                     'addedby': '2013-05-20 18:53:22', 
                     'imgtag': '30'}], 
                 'createdby': '', 
                 'procedure': 'kjnaksjncksdjnc'}]
             } //missing "\}"
        ]};
```